# (code) should be a lambda expression...what exactly am I missing?

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

So I know that usually this error means that I forgot a parenthesis somewhere (or something to that effect) but for the life of me, I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

The specific error I seem to be getting is: `(SETF (GET (NTH CNT EXOTIC-CARS) 'MAKE) (READ MYSTREAM))` - which is basically the first line of my first defined function.

The entire code is here:

```
(setq exotic-cars '(car1 car2 car3 car4 car5 car6 car7 car8 car9 car10))

(defun dostuff ()
(fetchinput)
  (printlist)
  (findmake)
  (mysort))

(defun fetchinput ()
  (with-open-file (mystream "cars.dat")
    (setq cnt 0)
    (loop while (<= cnt 9)
      do ((setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'make) (read mystream))
        (setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'model) (read mystream))
        (setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'cost) (read mystream))
        (setf cnt (+ cnt 1))
      )
      )))

(defun findmake ()
  (setf cnt 0)
  (format t "~2%~A ~A ~A ~A ~A" 'Car 'make 'to 'search 'for>)
  (setf search (read))
  (loop while (< cnt 10)
    do ((if (string= (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'make) search)
  (format t "~2%~1,15T ~A ~2,15T ~A ~3,15T ~A ~% ~A~%~1,15T ~A ~2,15T ~A ~3,15T $~D.00"    'Make 'Model 'Cost
    '------------------------------------- 
        (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'make)
        (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'model)
        (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'cost)))
    (setf cnt (+ cnt 1)))))

(defun mysort ()
  (setf unsorted 0)
  (loop while (< unsorted 9)
    do ((setf current 9)
    (loop while (> current unsorted)
      do ((if (< 
           (get (nth current exotic-cars) 'cost)
           (get (nth (- current 1) exotic-cars) 'cost))
          (swap current (- current 1)))
      (setf current (- current 1))))
  (setf unsorted (+ unsorted 1))))
  (printlist))

(defun swap (from to)
  (setf tmpmake (get (nth to exotic-cars) 'make))
  (setf tmpmodel (get (nth to exotic-cars) 'model))
  (setf tmpcost (get (nth to exotic-cars) 'cost))
  (setf (get (nth to exotic-cars) 'make) (get (nth from exotic-cars) 'make))
  (setf (get (nth to exotic-cars) 'model) (get (nth from exotic-cars) 'model))
  (setf (get (nth to exotic-cars) 'cost) (get (nth from exotic-cars) 'cost))
  (setf (get (nth from exotic-cars) 'make) tmpmake)
  (setf (get (nth from exotic-cars) 'model) tmpmodel)
  (setf (get (nth from exotic-cars) 'cost) tmpcost))

(defun printlist ()
  (setf cnt 0)
  (format t "~2%~1,15T ~A ~2,15T ~A ~3,15T ~A ~% ~A"    'Make 'Model 'Cost
    '-------------------------------------)
  (loop while (< cnt 10)
    do ((format t "~%~1,15T ~A ~2,15T ~A ~3,15T $~D.00" 
      (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'make)
      (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'model)
      (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'cost))
    (setf cnt (+ cnt 1)))))

(dostuff)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common lisp error: "should be lambda expression"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575819/common-lisp-error-should-be-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 5):

Without proper formatting and indentation, you'll get nowhere in programming.

Your code:

```
(defun fetchinput ()
  (with-open-file (mystream "cars.dat")
    (setq cnt 0)
    (loop while (<= cnt 9)
      do ((setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'make) (read mystream))
        (setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'model) (read mystream))
        (setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'cost) (read mystream))
        (setf cnt (+ cnt 1))
      )
      )))
```

Correct formatting:

```
(defun fetchinput ()
  (with-open-file (mystream "cars.dat")
    (setq cnt 0)
    (loop while (<= cnt 9)
          do ((setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'make) (read mystream))
              (setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'model) (read mystream))
              (setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'cost) (read mystream))
              (setf cnt (+ cnt 1))))))
```

The code has a bunch of problems:

```
(defun fetchinput ()
  (with-open-file (mystream "cars.dat")
    (setq cnt 0)                      ; <- the variable CNT is undefined
    (loop while (<= cnt 9)
          do (  ; <-  what is this parenthesis for ?

              (setf (get (nth
                          cnt
                          exotic-cars)  ;<- the variable exotic-cars is undefined
                         'make) (read mystream))
              (setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'model) (read mystream))
              (setf (get (nth cnt exotic-cars) 'cost) (read mystream))
              (setf cnt (+ cnt 1))
              )   ; < - what is this parenthesis for?
              )))
```

`SETF` does not declare/define variables. It just sets the value of declared/defined variables.

Why would you iterate over a list using `WHILE` and `NTH` ???

Answer (score 1):

Use `defvar` or `defparameter` to define global variables (and consider using "earmuffs" to signal them, so `(defvar *exotic-cars* ...)`).

Use `let` to declare and initialize local variables (so `(let ((cnt 0)) ...)`). Although in this case, you would probably be better off with `(loop for cnt from 0 to 9 ...)`, since it doesn't seem as if you need `cnt` outside the loop.

Lists are not magical, if you want to have a block of code, consider using `progn`.