# Why am I getting a "should be a lambda expression" error on this code?

Tags: lambda, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to create my own mapcar function in CLISP, without using mapcar. Every time I run my code, I get an error saying "... should be a lambda expression." I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
(defun my-map (f list)
   (if (not(NULL list))
      ((funcall f (car(list)))
        my-map (f (cdr(list))))))
```

If someone can tell me why I am getting this error, and if you see any additional errors, I would appreciate it. I am a beginner at CLISP.

Comment: Does the error refer to anything in particular in your code?  Can you explain how/why you think this should work?

Comment: So f would be the function name you want to use and list is the list of numbers you would pass to it. My thinking is that if the list is not null (it still has values), then you can do the function call f on the first element of the list. Then do a recursive call on the remaining portion of the list. The error I get when I try to load this is "(FUNCALL F (CAR (LIST))) should be a lambda expression".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common lisp error: "should be lambda expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575819/common-lisp-error-should-be-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Common Lisp function call looks like this:

```
(operator operands ...)
```

Unlike Scheme CL is a lisp2 which means the operator needs to be an identifier or a lambda form. Nothing else is allowed. In your code:

```
; <- operator ----------> <-- operands ... -->
((funcall f (car (list))) my-map (f (cdr (list))))
```

So there you have it. `(funcall f (car (list)))` is not an identifier or a lambda form.

Usually if you are making a `map` you would `cons` the result of calling the function on the first element with the recursion with the rest of the list.

Comment: How can I change my code to make this work? I still do not understand.

Comment: @Jonathan `(my-map #'1+ '(1 2 3))` should become `(cons (funcall #'1+ 1) (my-map #'1+ '(2 3)))` such that the result becomes `(2 3 4)`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but now it tells me (cons (funcall f (car (list))) (my-map (f (cdr (list))))) should be a lambda expression.

Comment: @Jonathan: Your probably have an extra set of parentheses around it.

Comment: @JonathanEvery time you get "should be a lambda expression" you are doing the exact same error again and as Scott mentions it is very often because of surplus parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make your return list by just putting a parenthesis in front of what goes in it; the interpreter thinks you are making a function call, which is why it is trying to interpret that expression as a function.  Instead, you need a function that returns a list with the result of calling `f` onto the head on the list you get by your recursive call.